# php app.yaml google app engine launcher

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am not a developer recently assigned a task to try put a simple static sites on google web hosting. I am stuck on the app.yaml part. The website works fine on a server I just couldn't get it to work on GAE.

```
handlers:

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: css

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: .*
  script: index.php 

folder
\css
\img
\js
about.php
footer.php
header.php
home.php
index.php
links.php
menu.php
```

If I leave the static dir line in the app.yaml the site will not start. If i only leave the script: index.php the page load but only the home page work and the header and footer or the CSS don't work.

I have read the google documents many times and get the hello world to work on my computer just can't get this simple site to work.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

Pay attention to the indentation, yaml is sensitive to that - you can have incorrect configs as a result (for example `static_dir: css` is not properly indented relative to `url: /stylesheets`, which is likely why you CSS is not working).

I presume the lower portion of the code section in the question is actually an illustration of your dir structure and not part of the app.yaml.file itself (which would be incorrect yaml syntax).

I don't see a favicon.ico file in your dir structure, the respective section in the app.yaml file is presently useless (or, if the file is somewhere else, the section needs to be corrected).

You don't have handlers for the other `.php` files, they're handled through the `.*` handler which is index.php (not sure if that's your intention).

You might want to go through this doc, many examples in there: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig

Update:

Assuming you want to add script handlers for all those `.php` files, one of the appconfig doc examples shows:

```
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

You'd need to place this above the catch-all `.*` handler (first matching handler is used, order matters).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply the lower part of the code is just the files and folder structure for my files as a reference for my question. In my app.yaml I have the code indented\aline properly. How do I add handler for other page?

Comment: You should edit the question and place the actual content/indentation of your `app.yaml` file, impossible to match your symptom descriptions with what we *might* imagine it looks like.

Comment: Dan, code you provide works now but the CSS, header and footer stand not working. I have updated the code above to reflect the actual indent in the app.yaml file.

Comment: Check your app logs in the Developer Console (or use chrome/firefox network view in the development tools, if you're familiar with them), see if the paths for the requests coming in are matching your expectations. Also watch closely the paths for which you get 404 (or other) errors. If using the network view you can also compare with the existing, working site and watch for deltas.

Comment: Any reason for serving the `/css` dir under `/stylesheets`? - just a shot in the dark, it's the only app dir which you "rename" in the app.yaml file and it's also the only one apparently not working... (the missing header/footer *might* be a side effect of the missing CSS)

Comment: the main.css file is store under the "css" folder that is what I declare as "/css". I use Chrome developer windows and I don't see any 404 errors. There is one line highlighted in red is the "modernizr-2.8.3.mini.js" it appears this file failed to load\time out.

Comment: Is `modernizr-2.8.3.mini.js` loaded from a CDN or provided by your site? Do you see the main.css file being requested and served in the network view? Pretty much you need to debug each missing piece: is it requested, is it found and served, if not then check the full path, find which handler is matching that path, etc...